# Procedure Entry Point Error

Tags: r, dll, rstudio, deflate, r-package

I'm trying to download a package but keep getting this error. Anyone have experience with it?

```
install.packages(c("devtools","rstudioapi"), dependencies=TRUE, repos=c("http://rstudio.org/_packages", "http://cran.rstudio.com"))

devtools::install_github(repo = "dadrivr/ffanalytics")

install.packages(c("devtools", "rstudioapi", "shiny", "miniUI", "data.table", "stringr", "DT", "XML", "httr", "tcltk", "RCurl", "Hmisc", "readxl", "RSelenium"), dependencies=TRUE, repos=c("http://rstudio.org/_packages", "http://cran.rstudio.com"))

library("ffanalytics"])
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in the question itself so we can copy/paste and try it ourselves.

Comment: Edited to reflect reproducible example

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for editing! Any advice?

Comment: No. This is a package I've never heard of. Probably better to open a GitHub issue for the author.